# Check the existence of file from 9 to 9:30 am using shell script and stop checking if file is found any time in between

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

My Intent is to check for files at different times for every 5 minutes and below is the aim and what I have implemented.

Aim :

```
  To check for file file1 from  9 to  9:30
  To check for file file2 from 11 to 11:30
  To check for file file3 from 10 to 10:30
  To check for file file4 from  4 to  4:30
```

> Check_File.sh

```
if [ -f /home/test/$1 ];  then
  echo "File \"/home/test/$1" exists”
else 
  echo "File not found"
fi
```

> updated code:

```
MESSAGE="Some message"
SUBJECT="Some subject"
RECIPIENT="somebody@somewhere.com"
filename=$1;
# Test for 30 minutes
for ((i=0;i<7;i++)) ; do
  echo "searching for file ${filename} `date` "
  if [ -f ./${filename} ];  then
   echo "File /home/test/${filename} exists"
   exit 0
  fi
 # Sleep 5 minutes
  echo "sleeping `date` as ${filename} file not found"
  sleep 300
done
echo "MAIL:File not found"
```

> cronjob entry

```
00-30/5  9 * * * /checkfile.sh file1 > /path/to/log/file/job1.log 2>&1
00-30/5 11 * * * /checkfile.sh file2 > /path/to/log/file/job2.log 2>&1
00-30/5 10 * * * /checkfile.sh file3 > /path/to/log/file/job3.log 2>&1
00-30/5  4 * * * /checkfile.sh file4 > /path/to/log/file/job4.log 2>&1
```

But if I find the file, I don't really want to check to happen and I am confused how to do it.

And if I do not find the file with in the specified time, I will have to send a mail. 
Is there any other way I could handle this problem.

Comment: If file is named Check_File.sh, you shouldn't call it with /checkfile.sh. Btw.: Is it really locate in the root dir?

Comment: Do you really want this running at 4:00 AM?

Comment: @ghoti file4 at 4 am to 4:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this run just once at the start of the 30 minute period from `cron`:

```
#!/bin/bash

MESSAGE="Some message"
SUBJECT="Some subject"
RECIPIENT="somebody@somewhere.com"

# Test for 30 minutes
for ((i=0;i<7;i++)) ; do
   if [ -f /home/test/"$1" ];  then
      echo "File /home/test/$1 exists”
      exit 0
   fi
   # Sleep 5 minutes
   sleep 300
done

# Failed to find file in specified time
echo "$MESSAGE" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" $RECIPIENT
```

---

A slightly different way of doing it is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MESSAGE="Some message"
SUBJECT="Some subject"
RECIPIENT="somebody@somewhere.com"

start=$SECONDS
# Test for 30 minutes
while : ; do
   if [ -f "/home/test/" ];  then
      exit 0
   fi
   ((elapsed=SECONDS-start))
   # Break out of loop if 30 minutes have elapsed
   [ $elapsed -ge 1800 ] && break
   # Sleep 5 minutes
   sleep 300
done
# Failed to find file in specified time
echo "$MESSAGE" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" $RECIPIENT
```

Comment: is the for loop for making the run time 35 minutes ?

Comment: Yes, it actually does the last check at 30 minutes but then waits 5 minutes, somewhat needlessly, before exiting. I didn't want to over-complicate it.

Comment: I guess you could make it `[ $i -lt 6 ] && sleep 300`

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the other solutions that allows you to designate a duration and interval at the command line, eg, run for 30 mins @ 5 min intervals, run for 60 mins @ 3 min intervals, etc.

NOTE: Borrowing Mark Setchell's mailx code ...

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=${1:-undefined}
durationmins=${2:-30}      # default to 30 min duration
sleepmins=${3:-5}          # default to  5 min intervals

MESSAGE="Some message"
SUBJECT="Some subject"
RECIPIENT="somebody@somewhere.com"

while true
do
        dt=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

        [ -f "${filename}" ]                        && \
        echo "${dt} - File '${filename}' exists"    && \
        exit 0

        durationmins=$((durationmins - sleepmins))

        [ ${durationmins} -lt 0 ] && break

        echo "${dt} - File '${filename}' not found, sleeping ${sleepmins} minute(s) ..."

        sleep $((sleepmins * 60))
done

dt=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

echo "${dt} - File '${filename}' not found, sending email ..."

echo "$MESSAGE" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" $RECIPIENT
```

Some sample invocations:

```
$ ./checkfile.sh file1 30  5        # check for 30 mins @  5 min intervals; 7 checks performed
$ ./checkfile.sh file2 60 10        # check for 60 mins @ 10 min intervals; 7 checks performed
$ ./checkfile.sh file3 15  7        # check for 15 mins @  7 min intervals; 3 checks performed
$ ./checkfile.sh file4              # defaults: check for 30 mins @ 5 min intervals; 7 checks performed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run the script once from cron, and have the script sleep for 5 minutes until the desired amount of time has elapsed, then send the email.  This way all state is contained within a single run of the script, and you don't need to write anything to disk to remember the state of prior runs.

Comment: But what if the computer boots at 9:15?

Comment: sorry , but i am not able to understand how to set the time and stop if file is found  and send a mail at end, well, i understand how to make the script sleep for 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You may create a timestamp file if you found a file:

```
if [ -f /home/test/$1 ];  then
  echo "File \"/home/test/$1" exists”
  touch /tmp/$1.timestamp
else 
  echo "File not found"
fi
```

If the time is X:30 (maybe with a tolerance of one minute), and there is no timestampfile from today, you can send the mail.

Touch will update an existing file with the current time and create a new one, if no file exists.